# How to set MTU for use with TCP_CORK

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

How do I set the MTU value pragmatically?

Apparently there are three candidates: `IP_MTU`, `TCP_MSS`, and `TCP_MAXSEG`

I tried:

```
uint16_t tcp_mss = 2048 * 8;

setsockopt(sock_descriptor, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MSS, &tcp_mss, sizeof(tcp_mss));
```

My intention is to increase the amount of data the TCP buffer should have before sending the packet.  `TCP_CORK` is in use.

Also helps if you know how to change the time from the apparent default of 200ms.

Comment: What is your outer problem exactly? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Streaming GBs of data on local net.  Noticed a significant improvement using TCP_CORK, now I need to push the MTU.

Comment: The MTU is a network parameter.

Comment: `uint16_t` is probably wrong. Most socket options take an `int`.